# Merge 2 tables with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I'm trying to merge two tables in one new with jQuery this way:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");

table.id = "mergedTable";

$("#mergedTable > tbody:last")
    .append($("#csvInfoTable2 > tbody").html())
    .append($("#csvInfoTable > tbody").html());
```

The problem is that I'm calling a HTML to CSV function and it says that mergedTable is empty. Also if I do `console.log(table)` it shows it empty. The tables have different numbers of columns but I need to generate something like:

```
col1,col2,col3 
col1,col2,col3 --> end table1
col1,col2,col3,col4 --> table2
col1,col2,col3,col4.
```

I'm using: https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/html5csv to generate the file and it works with csvInfoTable and csvInfoTable2 if I do separated.

Thanks

Comment: do you want this new table insterted in page also? If not you don't even need to give it an ID but you do need to store it as a new object variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not **appending** the newly created table. So `$("#mergedTable > tbody:last")` will fail.

And you should be using jQuery to create table, although you can do it in your way, but make sure you append it.

```
$('<table />', { id : "mergedTable" }).appendTo('body');
```

Note: If you want what @charlietfl suggests, then with your code, you would do

```
var tab = $(table).filter('> tbody:last')
    .append($("#csvInfoTable2 > tbody").html())
    .append($("#csvInfoTable > tbody").html());
```

Comment: you are assuming that OP even wants the resultant table in the DOM. My guess is it is only be created in order to generate CSV which can be done outside the DOM

Comment: @charlietfl whatever, he may be doing `$("#mergedTable > tbody:last")` will not work, which is why I did that

Comment: @charlietfl is it okay now?

Comment: I would assign it to a variable so it can be used for the CSV script also. Also worried that it may not even have a tbody in all browsers

Comment: Alot of the table/csv converters do require the object to be in the DOM.  It looks like this one also requires that in the way he is creating the object: var table = document.createElement("table");  Otherwise the converter would fail.

Answer (score 0):

For whom it may concern. I needed to merge two tables. The first was an asp.net Gridview, that is only at runtime an html table, and one htmltable i create dynamically. The javascript below is how i merge the two and make the latter table invisible by hiding the  it is in.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     // dit script plakt de rows van de ene tabel aan die van de tweede. 
     function AlignHeaders() {
         $("#tblHeader > tbody:last")
     .append($("#gvKlantInfo > tbody").html());
     }

     $('.divDatagrid').hide(); //this hides the second grid
```